# Firebase Function(scheduler/PubSub) Nodejs trigger but exit with that code:

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

Getting this error as my function trigger:

I'm using the same function and db

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change that function-scheduler setting and **maximize** its **timeout** from google cloud and redeploy it from there.

**DONE**

> Note: currently maximum timeout we can set is 9 minutes or 540 seconds.

*Additional*:

Default timeout can be changed here https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

**Steps to Follow:**

- Goto your function list via google cloud
- Find & Select your function by clicking on its name
- Select Edit from the top of the page
- Expand the "Runtime.....Settings"
- Set your time out and select next
- Finally, deploy it

  > **OR**
- **You can either manage it in your function internally in nodejs by following this:**
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802831/14190819