# Firebase functions times out, runWith options not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Note: i've set this up with [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

**Emulator**
When my firebase function takes more than 5 seconds, it returns
`{ code: "ECONNRESET" }`

The console shows:
`functions: Your function timed out after ~300s. To configure this timeout, see`
(although it endured only 5 seconds)

No matter the amount of timeoutSeconds set below.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true,
});

exports.app = functions.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 300
}).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    setTimeout(() => res.send({result: 'success'}), 5000);
  });
});
```

This problem occurs in the emulator `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

Also strange behavior in the console when the server responds after 4 seconds. It says after five seconds that it times out after 300 sec, although the app already finished:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "app"
i  functions: Finished "app" in 4102.929386ms
⚠  functions: Your function timed out after ~300s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

**Deployed**
When I deploy it, then the url shows this result, although I use cors

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /app from this server.
```

The versions in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
```

The documentation for: [runWith](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.runtimeoptions.md#runtimeoptions_interface)

Comment: Please share the entire function code and execution log. You might be doing something wrong.  We need to be able to reproduce what you've done.

Comment: You should use a cors module instead of trying to implement it yourself.  I don't think you're doing it correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: @DougStevenson that didn't solved the cors issue unfortunately, i've updated my code above so you can see it, thanks

Comment: Do you have any solution? I have the exact same problem and can't find what is wrong.

Comment: It seems like it is only in the emulator though, when I deploy it, things seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

runWith options did not work locally for me. I had to set this local env variable `FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR_TIMEOUT_SECONDS` https://stackoverflow.com/a/72396726/10668719.

But in regards to your functions timing out before the set timeout value. I ran into this problem when running in node v20

Found this github issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5363
The problem was fixed once I downgraded to node 18